# How to start a collector after previous collector collects something discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, collections, discord, discord.js

I am making a dank memer heist auto lock command in which I am starting 2 collectors with the same filters so both are collecting the first I want first collector to collect the first message and the 2nd one to collect the 2nd message

here's my code:

```
const filter = m => m.content.includes(message.author.username) && m.author.id === '270904126974590976';
const endf = e => e.content.includes(message.author.username) && e.author.id === '270904126974590976';
 message.channel.send('Listening for a heist in this channel. :eyes:')
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', m => {
    message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: true })
  message.lineReplyNoMention(`${verified} Successfully unlocked **${message.channel.name}** unlocking when heist ends.`)
})
const newcollector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(endf, { time: 90000 })

newcollector.on('collect', e => {
  message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: false })
  message.lineReplyNoMention(`${verified} Successfully locked **${message.channel.name}**`)
});

newcollector.on('end', collected => {
    message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: false })
  message.lineReplyNoMention(`${verified} Successfully locked **${message.channel.name}**`)
});
```

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62731621/15073477) help?

Comment: Put the 2nd collector in the callback of the 1st? Also, since both filters are identical you can merge them.

Comment: I tried putting `const filter = ....` there but it doesn't work is their something like `collector.start()`?